# Até quando teremos nossos votos de fechamento usurpados pelo sistema?

Tags: debate, bug, fechamento, razões-fechamento

Eu sei que já fiz [uma pergunta sobre isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5158/voto-de-fechamento-com-indica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-diferente-do-voto-escolhido) e mesmo apesar da resposta explicativa do Guilherme, continuo não concordando com a forma como o sistema exibe essa informação.

Entendo que o objetivo do voto é o fechamento, e que o motivo é algo para esclarecer melhor pro autor, mas ao linkar meu perfil no motivo de fechamento, eu estou sendo exposto pelo site.

E para provar isso, vejam essa pergunta de Java fechada como duplicata:

[Verificar se contém linhas no arquivo.txt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258638/28595)

Como vêem, como o perfil comunidade encerrou ela, provavelmente o autor aceitou a duplicata indicada por alguém, mas meu nome está claramente listado aí como um dos que indicou este motivo:

> marcada como duplicata por ÐvÐ, wmsouza, Articuno, Comunidade♦ 27 mins atrás
>   Esta pergunta foi feita antes e já tem uma resposta. Se essas respostas não abordarem completamente sua pergunta, faça uma nova pergunta.

Nao foi este o motivo que  eu escolhi, e uma forma simples de provar é ver que possuo voto vinculante nessa tag. Se eu fechasse como duplicata, nem haveria necessidade do autor aceitar.

Eu não concordo com essa exposição, afinal, eu votei como "não clara o suficiente"  e o site com frequência expõe os usuários em motivos que eles não escolheram. Ora, se o objetivo do voto é simplesmente fechamento, então não deveria haver essa "usurpação" de nossa escolha, que apresente o motivo mais selecionado sem apontar  ninguém que o escolheu, apenas que os usuários votaram pra fechar, pois isso induz a interpretações errada de quem lê, afinal se o box amarelo diz que Articuno votou como fora do escopo numa pergunta que faz parte do escopo, sendo que ele não votou nesse motivo, induz quem lê que Articuno analisou errado, quando não foi bem isso que ocorreu.

Comment: Eu entendo o incômodo. E se entendi bem o que aconteceu nos dois casos que você citou, foi o AP que concordou que era duplicata, fechando a pergunta com esse motivo antes dos 5 votos. O sistema considera que a concordância dele vale mais.

Comment: Existem várias feature requests no metão que trata exatamente desse assunto levantado aqui: [caso1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/229289), [caso2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16674/229289), [caso3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2519/229289) e inclusive um negado: [caso4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/926/229289). Todas elas de 2009 ou 2010. Ou seja, já é um assunto que incomoda vários usuários não é de hoje, eu inclusive, mas não sei o que mais temos que fazer para que nosso pedido fosse atendido.

Comment: [Mesma pergunta no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/208518).

Comment: @JNat está como "feature-request" desde 2010?

Comment: Aqui tem uma proposta de solução: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284886/ que inclusive menciona o post que o @JNat linkou - talvez seja o caso de comentar sobre os dois links na pergunta também.

Answer (score 10):

<sup><sub>Isso daqui era para ser um comentário, mas ficou grande demais.</sub></sup>

Penso que talvez devessemos colocar a tag [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) nesta pergunta, pois isso chamaria a atenção do pessoal da SO/SE. [edit: feito pelo Maniero].

O fato do sistema mentir descaradamente ao atestar falsamente que usuários realizaram determinadas ações que não sejam exatamente aquelas que eles de fato fizeram sem mais e nem menos não deve ser considerado como outra coisa senão um bug, não importando se esse bug é algo conhecido há anos.

O StackOverflow/StackExchange já tem nove anos de estrada. São centenas de comunidades ativas em plena operação e com tendência sempre para cima. Tudo isso é orquestrado por um software complexo, robusto, maduro e bem desenvolvido, que é mantido e monitorado por uma equipe muito talentosa, competente, organizada e altamente especializada. Trata-se de um sistema de importância fundamental e essencial para a SO/SE, afinal de contas, a companhia sem o software e a base de dados dele não é nada. Esse sistema é um ativo no qual foram e estão sendo investidos vários milhões de dólares, que rende outros tantos milhões e tem um valor agregado que é de mais alguns milhões, e isso tudo só cresce mais e mais dia após dia e cresce de forma sustentável e com excepcional qualidade.

Assim sendo, conclui-se que o problema não é orçamento, nem prazo, nem capacidade técnica, nem organização, e muito menos falta de perspectiva de futuro para o serviço. Burrice e falta de visão estratégica também não são o problema. Complexidade da implementação também não deve ser o problema, pois isso daí é algo que sabemos que eles devem resolver em algumas horas assim que começarem a trabalhar nisso.

Desta forma, considero ser uma vergonha inexplicável para a SO/SE ainda não ter corrigido um bug tão ridículo e bobo quanto esse. Dizer que isso é uma *feature* e que é intencional é desculpa esfarrapada, conversa para boi dormir. Não existe justificativa lógica para esse bug que não seja descaso, negligência e preguiça.

Até quando a SO/SE vai lidar com esse bug tal como faz o avestruz? Ou seja, enfiando a cabeça dentro de um buraco na terra para não ver nada. Até quando?

Comment: Concordo, não deixa de ser um bug.

Comment: Deixei um adendo em [comentário na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6628/at%c3%a9-quando-teremos-nossos-votos-de-fechamento-usurpados-pelo-sistema#comment25797_6628)